# MySQL - COUNT before INSERT in one query

Tags: mysql, insert, count

Hey all, I am looking for a way to query my database table only once in order to add an item and also to check what last item count was so that i can use the next number.

```
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM productr"
```

After that code above, i add a few product values to a record like so:

```
  ID | Product      | Price  | Description      | Qty | DateSold  | gcCode
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5  | The Name 1   | 5.22   | Description 1    | 2   | 09/15/10  | na
  6  | The Name 2   | 15.55  | Description 2    | 1   | 09/15/10  | 05648755
  7  | The Name 3   | 1.10   | Description 3    | 1   | 09/15/10  | na
  8  | The Name 4   | 0.24   | Description 4    | 21  | 09/15/10  | 658140
```

i need to count how many times it sees gcCode <> 'na' so that i can add a 1 so it will be unique. Currently i do not know how to do this without opening another database inside this one and doing something like this:

```
  strSQL2 = "SELECT COUNT(gcCode) as gcCount FROM productr WHERE gcCode <> 'na'
```

But like i said above, i do not want to have to open another database query just to get a count.

Any help would be great! Thanks! :o)

Comment: What is it that you want to make unique?

Comment: the gcCode count but i need to be able to add a new record at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two queries; one is a subset of the other which means getting what you want in a single query will be a hack I don't recommend:

```
 SELECT p.*,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM PRODUCTR 
          WHERE gccode != 'na') AS gcCount
   FROM PRODUCTR p
```

This will return all the rows, as it did previously.  But it will include an additional column, repeating the `gcCount` value for every row returned.  It works, but it's redundant data...

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do everything in one query. If you're using [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innodb) as a storage engine, you could wrap your `COUNT` query and your `INSERT` command in a single [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html) to guarantee [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity).

In addition, you should probably use `NULL` instead of `na` for fields with unknown or missing values.